# How to use Ruby CGI scripts on Uberspace

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cgi, uberspace

I want to use Ruby CGI scripts on an Uberspace 7, but ran into several issues with permissions and security settings, in particular when using gems. How do I install CGI scripts with custom gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that Uberspace 7 runs on SELinux. This means that CGI script files in `~/html/` not only have to be executable but also need the correct SELinux context. In this case, the type must be `httpd_sys_content_t`.

You can view the SELinux context with `ls -lZ`:

```
$ ls -Z file1
-rw-rw-r--  user1 group1 unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 file1
```

If some files have the wrong context, the context can be restored with the `restorecon` command, e.g. `restorecon -R ~/html/`.

The user installation directory for Ruby gems is `~/.gem/`. On Uberspace, `gem install` installs into that directory by default:

```
$ cat /etc/gemrc
gem: --no-document --user-install
```

As the home directory cannot be accessed by the apache process, gems installed there cannot be executed from CGI scripts. You can install gems in `/var/www/virtual/$USER/gem` instead, create the directory with

```
$ mkdir /var/www/virtual/$USER/gem
```

You cannot use the `--install-dir` parameter for `gem install` directly as this conflicts with the default parameters mentioned above:

```
$ gem install mygem --install-dir /var/www/virtual/$USER/gem
ERROR:  Use --install-dir or --user-install but not both
```

Instead, create `~/.gemrc` with the following content to override the default parameters (replace `<USERNAME>` with your actual user name):

```
gem: --install-dir /var/www/virtual/<USERNAME>/gem
```

Now the installation of gems should work:

```
$ gem install mygem
```

To use the gems in CGI scripts, set the `Gem.paths` variable before requiring gems:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

Gem.paths = { 'GEM_PATH' => '/var/www/virtual/<USERNAME>/gem' }

require 'mygem'

(... rest of the script)
```

This is needed as we cannot modify the environment variables (i.e. set `GEM_PATH`) for the apache process.

Comment: I just picked a random gem that I used for another project. Of course, rack doesn't make sense here, so I updated the reply. I sometimes use CGI for quick tests/prototypes. Having a functional script on a webserver within a few seconds is useful in 2018 too.

Comment: That's what things like [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) are good for. Since that's a Rack application you can use any [Rack web server](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/web_servers) and interface with it directly. CGI is really, really slow because it has to spin up a new process each time.